# How to install missing Python modules für QGIS on Manjaro?

Tags: python, manjaro

I installed QGIS via pamac UI just to find it complaining about two missing Python modules (osgeo, jinja2) needed for some of it's plugins. My first thought was to install them via pip, but pip refused to do that:

```
$ pip install osgeo
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try 'pacman -S
    python-xyz', where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.

    If you wish to install a non-Arch-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using 'python -m venv path/to/venv'.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip.

    If you wish to install a non-Arch packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use 'pipx install xyz', which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have python-pipx
    installed via pacman.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation
or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your
Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
hint: See PEP 668 for the detailed specification.
```

If I get this right, I have to use pacman to install system-wide packages:

```
$ sudo pacman -S python-osgeo
error: target not found: python-osgeo
```

And now I'm lost. Pip isn't working due to reasons, the advice how to do it is also not working. Can someone explain to me how to install python packages on Manjaro so that QGIS can  make use of it for it's plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this question on GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276898/qgis-3-0-cant-load-plugin-processing-no-module-named-osgeo-on-manjaro-linux):

Please try using `sudo pacman -S python-gdal` to install `osgeo`.